# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version' with ChromeDriverManager works on pycharm but doesn't on deepnote

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, deepnote

this code work on my computer with pycharm but doesn't work on deepnote server!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(version='114.0.5735.90').install()))
```

the error on deepnote:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "driver_version" instead of "version"?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the argument name you're looking for when using `ChromeDriverManager` is `driver_version` based on the docs [here](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager#version)

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

ChromeDriverManager(driver_version="2.26").install()
```

Their interface is inconsistent between classes which is likely what caused your issue. Some classes take a `version` argument like you tried, but `ChromeDriverManager` wants `driver_version`.